# How to create redirect page for all external link in blogger

Tags: javascript, html, redirect, blogger

I'm very new with these codes but i will try to explain for your better understand.

What I want, I want to create a page in blogger which will redirect after 5 - 10 sec. and just like php we can redirect any external url (download link) through that page. I found some code but it's not redirect properly, showing you below...

```js
<h3>Page Will Redirect After <span id="countdown">10</span> seconds</h3>

<!-- JavaScript part -->
<script type="text/javascript">
    
    // Total seconds to wait
    var seconds = 20;
    
    function countdown() {
        seconds = seconds - 1;
        if (seconds < 0) {
            // Chnage your redirection link here
            window.location = "https://www.google.com";
        } else {
            // Update remaining seconds
            document.getElementById("countdown").innerHTML = seconds;
            // Count down using javascript
            window.setTimeout("countdown()", 1000);
        }
    }
    
    // Run countdown function
    countdown();
    
</script>
```

```html
With this code i made a page (example: abc.blogspot.com/p/go.html) and i add link in post "<a href="http://abc.blogspot.com/p/go.html?redirect=www.facebook.com">LINK</a>"

but it's not redirect to facebook because in code mention : "window.location = "https://www.google.com";"
```

how can i make a redirect page with timer in blogger and rediect all external links in post with html code?

Comment: 1. What is blogger? Do you mean blogspot? And could you maybe clarify your question? It's hard to filter it out with all that gibberish

Comment: What you need to is to replace the google.com link with the "query parameter"

Answer (score 0):

You need to get the "query parameter" from the URL and change the google link to that.

```js
var seconds = 20;
var urlParams = new URLSearchParams(window.location.search);
var redirectLink = urlParams.get('redirect');
// CAUTION: assumes the redirectLink passed in URL is a valid URL.
// that is, it starts with a protocol - http://,  https://

function countdown() {
    seconds = seconds - 1;
    if (seconds < 0) {
        // Chnage your redirection link here
        window.location = redirectLink;
    } else {
        // Update remaining seconds
        document.getElementById("countdown").innerHTML = seconds;
        // Count down using javascript
        window.setTimeout("countdown()", 1000);
    }
}

// Run countdown function
countdown();
```

```html
<h3>Page Will Redirect After <span id="countdown">10</span> seconds</h3>
```

**Word of advice:** Unless you have a very good reason to do this, please don't.

1. A smart enough user will be able to see the redirect URL in the address bar anyway and use that to bypass your "please wait time".
2. It gives a bad user experience.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks @[Sudhanshu Vishnoi](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3367669/sudhanshu-vishnoi) It's working but whole page url with download link showing example below:

```html
<a href="http://abc.blogspot.com/p/go.html?redirect=http://www.mediafire.com/file/code.rar">LINK</a>
```

Is there any way to hide download link because you know how peoples are, they don't want 5 or 10 seconds and they will copy download link so i want to hide whole url or atleast download link, is this possible? if yes then how?

Comment: You can encode it in some non-legible form and decode it on the redirect page, but an above average user will be able to figure it out. Otherwise, you can create a server which maps certain random tokens to valid URLs. You'll need to add those tokens in your HTML.

Comment: I found some code for link cloaking in blogger but not working so i think it's not possible in blogger, right?